# Cisco ASAのACL設定について

Tags: network

暗黙のdenyが最後尾に入るのは基本ですが、明示的な「deny ip any any」を追加した後にdeny logは明示的なdenyを追加する前と同様に表示されますでしょうか？

Comment: deny log 無事に表示されました。